# Host Environment Security

Tags: java, linux, security, unix, hosting

I was just reading an article which explained how java can be used to run unix commands. Isn't this a possible threat to the environment the application is deployed in? What measures can the host system (assuming a unix/linux environment) use to prevent malicious scripts from being run?

Comment: It sounds like you have a specific use case in mind, you should elaborate.

Comment: @KErlandsson yes you are right. I was wondering about how companies which outsource their implementation work make sure their information is not stolen by some rogue code disguised as part of the application

Comment: @lemonTea - This problem isn't Java specific. Anytime you take code from elsewhere you run a risk. Managed languages like Java and .NET provide superior security over native languages like C++.

Answer (score 1):

The host system won't take any extraordinary measures beyond what is already common for the platform itself. It is up to the admin, implementers, or users to restrict what can happen on that platform, and follow best practices.

Some best practices:

1. For servers, it is best that the server processes run as a restricted user, and not a root or privileged user. Create a sandbox user for just that process.
2. Separate out HTTP Server (which might require root privileges to bind to port 80), from the Application Server, and have them run under separate users.
3. Make sure the user for the server processes only have access to local home, or dedicated user space, and no other parts of the host system.
4. Do not trust any program (whether it is a Java program or not), if it comes from a shady origin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Java won't run processes out of the blue... it needs to load a piece of code that tells it to run it, **plus** permissions from both Linux & the java security policy.
So even though it wold never be as safe as cutting off the internet connection ;) you could take reasonable precautions such as:

(1) On Unix level, make sure critical files/apps/etc are protected by permissions, and run Java with a less priviledged user

(2) Manage your java security policy, making it as strict as possible - e.g. access only directories required for the business

(3) Try not to leave holes for malicious code... e.g. if you have some creative classloaders that load remote code...  or if you expose some horrid RESTful service that executes any string it gets.

Obviously it should come with all the other hardening advises - DMZ, firewalls, secure coding practices (with INJECTION springing to mind), and obviously it helps to consult an expert.